# What's the best way to use web services in python?

Tags: python, web-services, soap

I have a medium sized application that runs as a .net web-service which I do not control,
and I want to create a loose pythonic API above it to enable easy scripting.

I wanted to know what is the best/most practical solution for using web-services in python.

Edit:
I need to consume a complex soap WS
and I have no control over it.

Comment: Are you trying to consume a SOAP WS? or write a web service/web app in Python? <http://diveintopython.org/soap_web_services/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jython](http://www.jython.org) and [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) give access to great Java & .NET SOAP libraries.

If you need CPython, [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/) has been flaky for me, but it could be possible to use a tool like [Robin](http://robin.python-hosting.com/) to wrap a good C++ SOAP library such as [gSOAP](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache Axis C++](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

If I have to expose APIs, I prefer doing it as JSON. Python has excellent support for JSON objects (JSON Objects are infact python dictionaries)

Comment: good tip about preferring JSON (although he doesn't control the web service), but JSON objects are not necessarily Python dictionaries - Python is missing "true", "false", and "null" (vs. "True", "False", and "None'). You still need a parser+stringifier.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the packages on python that a SOAP service through them can be called works on python 2.x, but had problems on Python 3.x

The best fit for python 3.x that I've found is [suds-jurko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.6)